# Consistent device id

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, unique-id, fingerprinting

Is there any way of getting a unique device id, that are consistent with nodejs/express/some npm module? I've tried with fingerprintjs2 on the clientside, but that isn't consistent, meaning I can get two different id's based on where I'm at.

It also needs to be without any use of saving cookies on the clientside, and has to be "calculated" with the same outcome everytime for each unique browser/user/whathaveyounot. The outcome has to be unique for each browser, somewhat similar to android-id in android.

EDIT: Im wondering this to try and create a login-free "service" that rely on the users device-id as login/username, releaving the user of all registration and whatnot

Comment: https://get.google.com/smartlock/

Comment: Perhaps combine your browser-side fingerprinting with some server-side IP address checking? Are you opposed to localstorage? Or to adding a UUID to the url somehow, and instructing users to only use that url? Fingerprintjs is accurate [only 94% of the time](https://panopticlick.eff.org/static/browser-uniqueness.pdf), and may change as you update your browser, etc.

Comment: The idea with not using cookies is so the user shouldn't be affected by clearibg their cache and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to identify an instance of a browser on the internet reliably. There are a multitude of reasons why we all use sign in systems, security and user validation is not an easy problem to solve.

If you want to ease the experience for the users look into using OpenID, your users will be able to log in using their existing google or facebook etc accounts fast and easy.

Comment: Ah, ok, then I might have to rethink somewhat how the service will work. Thanks for the answer!